# setting unique data attributes and ids for fields hidden by common class

Tags: jquery, html, backbone.js, backbone-views

There's an unworking fiddle for this question that'll probably show you what I'm trying to do better than the explanation below. http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/RRXnK/330/

I have a form with visible form labels, and a button below each label that the user should be able to click to display the form field, which is hidden using css. Each form field is hidden with the class

```
I love to play the piano. <-this is a form label
Click to Open Form <- this is a button that opens invisible form field

I practice five hours every day. <-this is a form label
Click to Open Form  <- this is a button that opens invisible form field
```

This is the css that hides the form fields

```
.span5.invisiblekey {
    display: none;
}
```

I want to click the button below each label and display the form field associated with each label. This is the JavaScript (using Backbone), but I can't figure out how to link the button with each specific form field so that only one form field is displayed when each respective button is clicked.

If possible, would you kindly help me figure out what to set in the ids and data-attributes of the form so that the JavaScript in `showForm` method can display the right form field?

```
var FormView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '#formscript', 

    events: {
        'click .fix': 'showForm'
    },

    showForm: function () {
        alert("form clicked");
    }

});

var form_view = new FormView();
```

This is the html. There is some flexibility as to what I can set the data attributes and ids

```
<div id="formscript">
<div class="row">
    <p class="span3">
        <label for="title">I love to play the piano.</label> 
       <a class="btn btn-small btn-warning fix" data-i-love-to-play-the-piano="i-love-to-play-the-piano" href="#">Click to Open Form</a> 
    </p>
    <p class="span3">
        <input class="span5 invisiblekey" data-i-love-to-play-the-piano="i-love-to-play-the-piano" id="i-love-to-play-the-piano" name="i-love-to-play-the-piano" type="text" value="">
    </p>
</div>

    <div class="row">
       <p class="span3">
         <label for="I_practice_five_hours_every_day.">I practice five hours every day.</label>
          <a class="btn btn-small btn-warning fix" data-i-practice-five-hours-every-day="i-practice-five-hours-every-day" href="#">Click to Open Form</a>  
         </p>
         <p class="span3">
            <input class="span5 invisiblekey" id="i-practice-five-hours-every-day"  name="i-practice-five-hours-every-day" type="text" value="I practice five hours every day.">
         </p>             
    </div>        
 </div>//formscript id
```

Update

Note, if it makes a difference, in my actual (Rails) app, the html is inside a form with an id #new_group

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/entries/11/corrections" class="nifty_form" id="new_group" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery?  Your fiddle is pulling it in, but you didn't tag your question with it...

Comment: @dc5 yes I am sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example on how you can do it with you current HTML structure:

```
showForm: function (e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).closest(':has(.invisiblekey)').find('.invisiblekey').removeClass('invisiblekey');
}
```

However that's not very efficient, what you could do instead is rename your `data-name-of-the-field="name-of-the-field"` attributes to something like `data-field-id="id-of-the-field"`, then you could do:

```
$('#' + $(e.target).attr('data-field-id')).removeClass('invisiblekey');
```

EDIT: You should strongly consider using the approach in @Sushanth--'s solution.

Comment: Why not something simpler and more robust like `$(e.currentTarget).closest('.row').find('.span5').show()`? And you might want to tell them that their `<label>`s don't have the right `for` attributes while you're at it.

Comment: @muistooshort, Well I didn't bother since it isin't the correct approach anyway. I updated the example for something slightly better.

Comment: @muistooshort can you please tell me what's wrong with the `for` attributes of the `<label>`s

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil: ["The value of the id attribute on a form control for which the label is a caption."](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/label.html#label.attrs.for)

Answer (score 2):

I feel it is a bad practice to be using Backbone and using jQuery logic to manipulate the data as this causes tight coupling between the views and the `DOM` which is not a good practice.  The preferred way is to use templates that show the corresponding data, so that that is specific to that particular view.

If you can separate them out into each view , then you would not be needing data-attributes in the first place as you can search for the elements in the specific view itself. And your starting `HTML` footprint will be very small.

**Template**

```
    <div id="formscript">
    </div>

   <!-- Created a template for each form view -->
    <script type="text/template" id="row-template">
            <p class="span3">
                <label for="title"><%= name %></label> 
                <a class="btn btn-small btn-warning fix" href="#">Click to Open Form</a> 
            </p>
            <p class="span3">
                <input class="span5 invisiblekey" type="text" value="<%= name %>" />
            </p>
    </script>
```

**Javascript**

```
 // Model that holds the data for the view
    var Form = Backbone.Model.extend({
        idAttribute: 'id'
    });

    var Forms = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Form
    });

    // Add the models to the collection
    var forms = new Forms([{
        name: "I love to play the piano",
        id: 1
    }, {
        name: "I practice five hours every day",
        id:2
    }]);

   // This is the view for each form Item
    var FormItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
        className: 'row',
        events: {
            'click .fix': 'showForm'
        },
        // Template structure for the view
        template : _.template($('#row-template').html()),
        // This is the only code required for the input 
        // to be shown                                  
        showForm: function () {
            $('.span5.invisiblekey', this.$el).toggle();
        },
        // Rendering the View for each model passed
        render: function () {
            this.$el.append(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });

    // This will be the main view
    var FormView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#formscript',
        // Method that initializes each view for a model
        // and renders it
        renderFormItem: function(form) {
            var formItemView = new FormItemView({
                model: form
            });
            this.$el.append(formItemView.el);
            formItemView.render();
        },
        render: function() {
            // Iterate over the collection and render a view
            // for each model in the collection
            var thisView = this;
            this.$el.empty();
            _.each(this.collection.models, function (form) {
                thisView.renderFormItem(form);
            });
            return this;
        }
    });


    // Initialize the form and call render
    var form_view = new FormView({
        collection: forms
    });
    form_view.render();
```

### **[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/RRXnK/335/)**

jQuery can be used in many ways to implement the same functionality. But when you are using backbone specifically, why not use the options that Backbone has to offer, instead of pure DOM manipulation that will cause tight coupling between the `views and the DOM` which is not a good sign if you want to write scalable applications.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to use backbone, but you can do what you're asking by having a `data-form` attribute on the button, and selecting the form based on the id contained in this field.

I have edited your input id so id does not have spaces (which are not valid in id attributes). You still need to remove the spaces on the name attribute as well.

HTML

```
<a class="btn btn-small btn-warning fix" data-form="i-love-the-rain" href="#">Fix It</a>
<input class="invisiblekey" id="i-love-the-rain" name="correction[data][I love the rain.]" type="text" value="">
```

JavaScript

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    id = $(this).data('form');
    // Three methods to show element
    // $('#' + id).show();
    // $('#' + id).toggleClass('invisiblekey');
    $('#' + id).removeClass('invisiblekey');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BqGK7/1/

Comment: I added the data form attribute to the button `<a class="btn btn-small btn-warning fix" data-form="i-love-the-rain" href="#">Fix It</a>` Can you show me in jquery (which I will add to the backbone) how to select and make visible this form field for which the `invisiblekey` class is set to display:none `<input class="invisiblekey" id="correction_data_I love the rain." name="correction[data][I love the rain.]" type="text" value="">` Thanks if you can help.

Answer (score 1):

If your markup is always known you could use navigate through the dom using something like previousElementSibling (or previousSibling depending on compatibility needs):

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RRXnK/334/)

Ugly version but it works for chrome/safari (not cross all browsers/versions)...

```
showForm: function (evt) {
    evt.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild.classList.remove('invisiblekey');
}
```